# How do I display a MediaWiki image's file description as its caption?

Tags: image, mediawiki, wikipedia, caption

I want to display an image on our MediaWiki site using the description from its file description page  as the caption in the syntax `[[File:imagename.png|frame|caption]]`. To clarify, I'm not trying to link to the image's description page.

I've read some things about querying the API on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942066/how-to-get-the-full-image-comments-using-the-wikipedia-api) but I'm struggling to see how I can display the result of the query on the property (be it `iiprop=comment` or `rvprop=content` or...something else) in the source itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a locally uploaded file, and your description pages don't have extraneous formatting, you could get away with something like this:

```
[[File:imagename.png|frame|{{File:imagename.png}}]]
```

But there's plenty of ways that can go wrong...

Comment: And of the description pages contain more than the text to include, you could use something like `<onlyinclude>`, right?

Comment: @Brion: This works very nicely; thank you. Could you give me an example of what kind of formatting that might cause a problem? I added a span and some bold markup to my description to test the solution and had no problems.

Comment: @skia.heliou, it's called [transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Transclusion). Any MediaWiki page can be used as a template. The simplest way that can go wrong is the presence of a `]]` or `|` which gets added in the markup of your image, breaking it.